# How do I find highest value using pointer?

Tags: c++

I want to find the highest value from an array using two given pointer `int *p,*max;`, but the code doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int a[10], i, index;
  int *p, *max;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) cin >> a[i];
  max = 0;
  p = &a[10];
  for (index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
    if ((p[index]) > *max) {
      *max = (p[index]);
    }
  }
  cout << "Highest value=" << *max << endl << "is at index=" << index << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if((p[index])>*max){` on the first iteration `max` is a null pointer. So you can't dereference it. `*max=(p[index]);` is also wrong for a similar reason.

Comment: [std::max_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element).

Comment: what does it mean? max is initiated to zero, so the first index value will be bigger than max n that index value would be assigned to max in the next line

Comment: ive declared max=0;

Comment: Which means you can't do `*max` because `max` is a null pointer.

Comment: `max` is indeed initialized to 0,  but `max` is a pointer. That means you pointed it at address 0.

Comment: should it have been done like int c=0; *max=&c ?

Comment: If you are required to use a pointer, max should always point to an item in a. instead of max = 0 you should have max=&a[0]; or just max = a;

Comment: Close. But when you want to assign an address to a pointer, you typically don't want to dereference the pointer.

Comment: i cant use max_element, ive to do it manually

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a problem description. What result does it produce? Why is that wrong?

Comment: Do you have to use `p`?

Comment: yes, i have been given two pointers p and max.

Answer (score 1):

The code is buggy. First of all, you assign

```
p=&a[10];
```

This assigns `p` to a memory address *past* `a`. Furthermore, you then index as `p[index]`, which essentially is the same as `a[10 + index]`.

Also, `max` is a wild pointer. It does not point to anything. You are assigning values to an undefined memory location.

I would strongly suggest to read up on pointers and to properly understand them before using them. Also, in modern C++, it is not very often than you need pointers.

Also, in idiomatic C++, we would probably write

```
auto p = std::max_element(a, a + 10);
```

Comment: This `p=&a[10];` will lead to UB later

Comment: It's perfectly fine to take that address here (it's just arithmetic), but reading from p or writing to p is definitely an UB.

Comment: when `index >=0` then this is clearly UB: `p[index]`!

Comment: We agree about that. `p[index]` is reading from `p`, since it dereferences `p` at `index`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem is recognizing that max should always point to the maximum item seen in the array a so far so instead of initializing max to 0 you start by initializing it to point to the first item in a which is &a[0] or just a.

I tried to make the least amount of changes to the original code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a[10],i,index;
    int *p,*max;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        cin>>a[i];
    max=a; // Initialize max to point to the first item in a
    p=a;
    for(index=0;index<10;index++){
        if((p[index])>*max){
            max=(&p[index]); // Now make max point to the new maximum item
        }
    }
    cout<<"Highest value="<<*max<<endl<<"is at index="<<max - p<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the code in ideone:
https://ideone.com/BwE45C

As mentioned in the comments below `p` probably is not being used as the question expects so I have rewritten the code to iterate using `p`

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a[10],i,index;
    int *max;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        cin>>a[i];
    max=a;

    for(int* p=a;p<a+10;p++){ // p is now a pointer that is used to iterate through the array
        if(*p>*max){
            max=p; // max points to the new maximum 
        }
    }
    cout<<"Highest value="<<*max<<endl<<"is at index="<<max - a<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The new ideone link for this is here: https://ideone.com/bk3zoS

Comment: Some code to follow. I have to figure out what `p` should be used for.

Comment: Probably expected to `p++` to iterate. Something like `if(*p>*max){ max=p; } p++;`

Comment: If you wanted in both codes you can start with a[1] instead of a[0] in the last loop. That would eliminate 1 pointless comparison of *max to itself.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems.

First, `p` should point to the array's first element, so you should have `p = &a[0]`.
You can also rely on implicit conversion and just write `p = a;`, which is exactly the same.
`&a[10]` is the pointer "one-past-the-end" of the array, and dereferencing it is undefined.

Next, you want `max` to *point to* the maximum element.
It should also start at the beginning of the array, like `p`.

Then, when you find a new maximum, you should make `max` point to that element, not change the value `max` points to.

Lastly, `index` will always be 10 after the search loop.
(Take a few moments to think about why.)
You don't need it – the index is the difference between the location of the maximum element and the beginning of the array.

```
int main()
{
    int a[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cin >> a[i];
    int* max = &a[0];
    int* p = &a[0];
    for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++){
        if (p[index] > *max){
            max = &p[index];
        }
    }
    cout << "Highest value= " << *max << endl << "is at index= "<< max - a << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd remove `p` and use a range-based for-loop where possible and iterators when it'll improve performance.

Comments in the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

// using namespace std; // don't do this

int main() {
    using std::cin, std::cout;

    int a[10];

    // use a range-based for-loop:
    for(int& aref : a) { // aref is a reference to the current element in a

        // check that extraction from std::cin actually works
        if(!(cin >> aref)) {
            std::cerr << "error reading int\n";
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // initialize max to point at the first element
    auto max = std::begin(a);

    // Start at the second element since max is already set to point at the first element.
    // Don't use magic numbers. Define a constant or use std::size(<array>)
    // ...or use iterators like in this example:
    for(auto curr = std::next(std::begin(a)); curr != std::end(a); ++curr) {
        if(*curr > *max) {
            max = curr;
        }
    }

    // you can use std::distance ot calculate the index for max:
    cout << "Highest value=" << *max << '\n'
         << "is at index=" << std::distance(std::begin(a), max) << '\n';
}
```